# googlemap location is not displaying on android mobile

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

android Mobile device location is not appearing.
let me know how to fix this issue ?

```
this is my code


     <MapView #mapView [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom" [minZoom]="minZoom"
                            [maxZoom]="maxZoom" [bearing]="bearing" [tilt]="tilt" i-padding="50,50,50,50"
                            [padding]="padding" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"></MapView>

AndroidManifest.xml file

  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCMGHElUuIQAyOEo**********" />
```

[image]

Comment: You mean the map shows empty space, doesn't populate anything?

Comment: yes only google icon only displaying

Comment: Do you have Play Services installed in your Emulator? If not, it will not work in Emulator. Though it's possible to install Play Services, it may not be easy & consistent. I would recommend using a device for testing.

Comment: I tested an android device same issue running

Comment: Are you sure you signed the application with the same certificate you used to generate the key.

Comment: not yet i tested through apk file .